# Subtraction of a simple 1D array looks incorrect

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

As an array, I have data and background. The array has a shape of (1024,). I want to subtract background from data and I use the following code, but the result looks strange and is incorrect. I don't understand why. The result from the code is shown in figure.

```
background=(np.array(data[0][0][0])).reshape(1024,1)
data = (np.array(data[2][0][0])).reshape(1024,1)
signal = np.subtract(data,background)
```

[image: Figure showing data and results from the above code as signal]

Comment: Could you attach all of your code please? It is not possible to debug on the basis of an image.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. The datatypes were uint16 which were then converted to float using `background= data[0][0][0].astype(np.float16)`